# ggplot: customize x-axis to a specific value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to customize the x-axis line to a specific mean value for bar graph and all the bar higher then that specific value shuld be above that line and bars with lower values should be below that line.

I have tried this code but it is only showing a sparate horzontal line

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=reorder(Genotype, -Pn), y=Pn, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black",position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#AFABAB', '#404040', '#1A1110')) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Pn-se_Pn, ymax=Pn+se_Pn), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1), position = "top")+
  geom_text(data = data, aes(y = Pn+0.1, label = g_Pn),position = position_dodge(width = .75),angle = 90)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, linetype = "solid", color = "red")
```

but I need a graph look like this in the attched image  which i created in excel.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)   # just for the sample ata
library(ggplot2)
quux <- count(ggplot2::mpg, class) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  mutate(class = factor(class, levels = class))
horiz <- 40 # your choice
ggplot(quux, aes(class)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin=as.numeric(class)-0.4, xmax=as.numeric(class) + 0.4, 
        ymin=pmax(horiz, n), ymax=pmin(horiz, n))
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete()
```

[image: ggplot2 with bars up and down]

Comment: You could do `ggplot(quux, aes(x = class)) + scale_x_discrete() + ... ` to avoid setting the breaks and labels via `scale_x_continuous`. But I was told that this is even harder to explain in words. :D

Comment: yup, just the tweak it needed, thanks @stefan

Comment: Haha. And now you teached me that I could add the `scale_x_discrete` anywhere in the code. For whatever reason I made it a habit (and was convinced that I have to) to add it straight after `ggplot()`. :D

Comment: I've see `aes(.)` outside of `ggplot(.)` and `geom_*(.)` as well, it appears order of arguments to `ggplot` does nothing other than dictate the order of layers, not much more. @stefan

Comment: @r2evans could yoy please tell me, how could i move the x-axis labels (suv, compact .... etc) close to horiz value?

Comment: Try `+ geom_text(aes(label = class, y = horiz), angle=90, hjust = 1.1) + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())`

Comment: It worked thanks, once more 