# how can arrange multiple whisker plot in descending order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to arrange this plot in descending order, along with all other `aes`.

[image]

| Genotype | Specie | Pn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BGB001 | sp1 | 0.294 |
| BGB001 | sp1 | 0.281 |
| BGB001 | sp1 | 0.012 |
| BGB001 | sp1 | 0.027 |
| BGB003 | sp2 | 0.098 |
| BGB003 | sp2 | 0.121 |
| BGB003 | sp2 | 0.080 |
| BGB003 | sp2 | 0.140 |
| BGB008 | sp3 | 0.136 |
| BGB008 | sp3 | 0.266 |
| BGB008 | sp3 | 0.111 |
| BGB008 | sp3 | 0.025 |
| BGB009 | sp1 | 0.048 |
| BGB009 | sp1 | 0.104 |
| BGB009 | sp1 | 0.046 |
| BGB009 | sp1 | 0.010 |
| BGB011 | sp2 | 0.179 |
| BGB011 | sp2 | 0.165 |
| BGB011 | sp2 | 0.297 |
| BGB011 | sp2 | 0.284 |

codes I am using are these
`ggplot(data, aes(x=Genotype, y=Pn, fill=Specie))+stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+ scale_fill_manual(values=c('#e9002d', '#ffaa00', '#00b000')) +  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA,linetype = 3)`

Comment: (1) Every question on SO and [tag:ggplot2] that asks about "order" with regards to axis, boxes, whiskers, etc, is resolved by converting the nominal/ordinal variable to `factor`s and controlling its `levels=`. (2) You're unlikely to get help with code and sample data, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on _reproducible questions_.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3253641/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12774210/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18401931/3358272; ordering with groups https://stackoverflow.com/q/44350031/3358272

Comment: And you asked effectively the same question before, [and I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76955988/3358272).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but all of these methods didn't work when I tried to work with multiple box plots.

Comment: here is the example date I am working with `Genotype Specie Pn
BGB001 sp1 0.294
BGB001 sp1 0.281
BGB001 sp1 0.012
BGB001 sp1 0.027
BGB003 sp2 0.098
BGB003 sp2 0.121
BGB003 sp2 0.080
BGB003 sp2 0.140
BGB008 sp3 0.136
BGB008 sp3 0.266
BGB008 sp3 0.111
BGB008 sp3 0.025
BGB009 sp1 0.048
BGB009 sp1 0.104
BGB009 sp1 0.046
BGB009 sp1 0.010
BGB011 sp2 0.179
BGB011 sp2 0.165
BGB011 sp2 0.297
BGB011 sp2 0.284`

Comment: and here is the code I am using ```ggplot(data, aes(x=Genotype, y=Pn, fill=Specie)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#e9002d', '#ffaa00', '#00b000')) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA,linetype = 3)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several "descendings" you can choose here, but:

1. they all rely on knowing how to calculate the boxplot statistics (easy with `boxplot(..., plot=FALSE)`, and
2. they all result in using `factor(., levels=.)` to show ggplot how you want the ordinal/nominal variables ordered.

```r
bp <- boxplot(Pn ~ Genotype, data = data, plot = FALSE)
bp
# $stats
#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
# [1,] 0.0120 0.0800 0.0250 0.010 0.1650
# [2,] 0.0195 0.0890 0.0680 0.028 0.1720
# [3,] 0.1540 0.1095 0.1235 0.047 0.2315
# [4,] 0.2875 0.1305 0.2010 0.076 0.2905
# [5,] 0.2940 0.1400 0.2660 0.104 0.2970
# $n
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4
# $conf
#          [,1]     [,2]    [,3]    [,4]     [,5]
# [1,] -0.05772 0.076715 0.01843 0.00908 0.137885
# [2,]  0.36572 0.142285 0.22857 0.08492 0.325115
# $out
# numeric(0)
# $group
# numeric(0)
# $names
# [1] "BGB001" "BGB003" "BGB008" "BGB009" "BGB011"
```

From `?boxplot`, we know that `$stats` is

```
   stats: a matrix, each column contains the extreme of the lower
          whisker, the lower hinge, the median, the upper hinge and the
          extreme of the upper whisker for one group/plot.  If all the
          inputs have the same class attribute, so will this component.
```

I'll choose (for sake of demonstration) the upper hinge (`$stats[4,]`):

```r
data |>
  transform(Genotype = factor(Genotype, levels = bp$names[order(-bp$stats[4,])])) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=Genotype, y=Pn, fill=Specie)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#e9002d', '#ffaa00', '#00b000')) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA,linetype = 3)
```

[image: descending order]

Choose whichever stat or combination of stats that makes sense to you.